# what does " Plant Your arse" mean?

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

What Does " Plant your arse" mean? for example in greeting? And Is it Rude and offensive? or is politely? 
or if its meaning changes in different situations please explain. And please provide me some synonyms.

Comment: It means _Siddown!_; plain speaking, informal speech. Often used between old friends or colleagues, or to simulate friendship and collegiality in the appropriate context.

Comment: Worth mentioning also that the degree of offence the expression might cause will vary from 0 to a very large number, depending on context, tone of voice, relationship between speaker and speakee, the usual factors.

Comment: I think that should probably be spelt *"Plant your ass"* - it looks like an AmE variant on BrE *"Park your bum"*.

Comment: Isn't "arse" BrE, @FumbleFingers?  I suspect that "Plant your ass" might be used in the US...where, I'm not sure.

Comment: Kristina Lopez, yes. *Arse* is the word in the UK.

Comment: Also heard as '_Park_ your arse' together with a nod towards a chair, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used in informal speech in the UK, but not in polite speech.  Said harshly, it could be a command to be still.  Said as you walk into your local pub, a friendly invitation to share a drink.

"arse" being an inflected corruption of "ass," and in "butt."  To "plant your arse" means to literally sit down.

Comment: In fact 'ass' is a corruption of 'arse' not the other way around. *Ass* means donkey but has come to mean 'buttocks' in US English.  The word 'arse' goes all the way back to Old English ærs "tail, rump"   http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=arse&searchmode=none

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It’s not so much that _donkey_ came to mean _butt_, but rather that the r was lost. There has been a sporadic tendency to reduce root-final /rs/ to /s/ throughput the history of English; it’s never been a general thing, but it’s left its mark here and there; compare _bass_ (the fish) from earlier _bærs_; _cuss_ from _curse_; _bust_ from _burst_; etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that the English is actually "park your arse", a slightly rougher version of the less offensive "park your bum" (all my students understand this!)  I can't say for sure what the AmE version is, but I'd guess it involves changing the BrE "arse" or "bum" to AmE "ass" or "butt".

Also, there's the AmE "park your booty", but this has sexual connotations.

Answer (score 0):

[Plant your ass](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assplant),  and  assplat: slang and impolite:

> - The origin came from skateboardings all accidents when you fell on the ass, and the word assplant came up naturally. Then it became a thing to jump around and "plant the ass" on different kinds of thing.
>
>   - For example plant you ass on the roof of a car by jumping up and sit on it. 
>       Or if you accidentally fell, you can say you made a assplant.

Source:http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assplant

Comment: It goes a long way further back than skateboards!